# Low Yearly Archives

Tags: low-yearly-archives

Im trying to use Low Yearly Archives to show a list months with a list to an individual month of articles.

I also want to show a list of years excluding the current year so the page will look something like this:

Jan
Feb

2014
2013
2012

Ive had this running on earlier versions of EE but can't get it join on 2.9

Here is the code:

PHP:

```
<?php
$year = $this->EE->localize->decode_date("%Y", $this->EE->localize->now);
?>
```

Tag:

```
{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news" start_month="1" status="not closed" sort="desc" show_future_entries="no" start_year="<?=$year?>" end_year="<?=$year?>" dynamic="yes"}
{months}
{if num_entries > 0}
<a href="{site_url}news/archive/{year}/{month_num}/" title="{num_entries} entries in {month} {year}">{month}</a> | {num_entries}
{/if}
{/months}
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}

{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="news" status="not closed" sort="desc" end_year="<?=$year-1?>" dynamic="no"}
{if year == "<?=$year?>"}
{if:else} 
{if entries_in_year > 0}
<a href="{site_url}news/year/{year}/" title="{entries_in_year} entries in {year}"><strong>{year}</strong></a>
{/if}
{/if}
{/exp:low_yearly_archives}
```

Im sure it has something to due with the php part but I can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I needed to change: decode_date to format_date

```
<?php
$year = $this->EE->localize->format_date("%Y", $this->EE->localize->now);
?>
```